# synaptics touchpad in linux can single tap twice to drag, but not double tap twice

Tags: linux, arch-linux, touchpad, synaptics-touchpad, xinput

I'm using Arch Linux with i3 window manager. I have tap-to-click and also tap-to-drag enabled in xinput, so currently if tap twice with one finger, it successfully drags. Additionally, tapping once with two fingers works like clicking the right mouse button.

However, tapping twice with *two* fingers, doesn't drag with the right mouse button. (I know it doesn't work because if it did, I would be able to resize windows with it). I suspect because two finger movement on touchpad is reserved for scrolling.

How can I enable two finger double tap to drag?

I'm currently using Arch linux with kernel 5.2.0 and xinput version 1.6.2, and here's the output for

```
bash $ xinput list-props 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'

Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (165):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (167): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (300): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (301): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (302):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (303):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (304):   1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (305):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (306):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (307):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (308):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (309):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (310):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (311):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (312):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (313):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (314):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (315): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (316):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (317):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (318):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (319):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (320): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (321): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (322): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (323): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (285): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (286):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (287):    0, 0
    Device Node (288):  "/dev/input/event8"
    Device Product ID (289):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (324):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (325):   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [not yet supported](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues/1) in libinput.

As an alternative, you can try installing the old `xf86-input-synaptics` driver (which is no longer maintained, but had some additional features).

Update: This is [finally supported](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/merge_requests/463) in libinput 1.17.0.

Comment: If you think it's supported now, maybe you could say how to enable it, as that is indeed the question?